# Laravel Eloquent Select Between current month and previous 3 months

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, php-carbon

i'm trying to build a query that will select all of the records in my DB between now (current month) and the previous 3 months.

My query somewhat works, but i want to ignore the day of the month. At the moment, it's selecting the last # of months to the current DAY as well but i want to ignore the current day and use the start and end of the months.

Here's my query:

```
$dateS = Carbon::now()->subMonth(3);
$dateE = Carbon::now(); 
$TotalSpent = DB::table('orders')
->select('total_cost','placed_at')
->whereBetween('placed_at',[$dateS,$dateE])
->where(['deleted' => '0', 'delivery_address_id' => $DeliveryAddress->id])
->sum('total_cost');
```

Any help would be appreciated. It's really bugging me!

Comment: Then dont use now, and specify the dates by creating new date with first day is simple, last day would be next minus one day.

Comment: `echo (new Carbon('first day of December 2008'))->addWeeks(2);     // 2008-12-15 00:00:00`
From their [page](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) so if there is "first day" you could get 'last day" too:) *assumption

Comment: if it helps you then please accept the answer bro

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will do the trick I guess

```
$dateS = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth(3);
$dateE = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(); 
$TotalSpent = DB::table('orders')
->select('total_cost','placed_at')
->whereBetween('placed_at',[$dateS,$dateE])
->where(['deleted' => '0', 'delivery_address_id' => $DeliveryAddress->id])
->sum('total_cost');
```

`startOfMonth()` begins with 1st date of the month

Comment: Watch your typos: `Carbon::now()startOfMonth();` is a syntax error.

Comment: pleasure bro :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Carbon:

```
$data = Data::where("created_at",">", Carbon::now()->subMonths(6))->get();
```

You need to import the namespace to use Carbon:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```