# how to get data only for one month?

Tags: sql, laravel, routes

The code is for `get` data by location:

```php
$staffs = \App\Worker::whereIn('idLoc', [21,23,42,112])->get();
$start = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '01-01-2019')->firstOfMonth();
$end = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '01-01-2019')->lastOfMonth();
```

All I need is the data output shown in one month.

Comment: You'll want a `whereBetween` in your query that uses `$start` and `$end` as its argument.

Comment: change whereIn to whereBetween? its that what u means? @ceejayoz

Comment: No, the `whereIn` filters by `idLoc`, which you presumably still need.  You need a separate `whereBetween` to filter THOSE results with the dates you have already created.

Comment: oh create other filter to make selection date?@TimRoberts

Answer (score 0):

**answer as per laravel 8**

```
$data = Item::select('*')
            ->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->get();
   
print_r($data);
```

```
$currentMonth = date('m');
$data = DB::table("items")
            ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$currentMonth])
            ->get();
  
print_r($data);
```

[similar question click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172587/laravel-eloquent-select-between-current-month-and-previous-3-months)